# why i can't get display last 2 char and it's getting error why?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
   char char1 = 'M';
   char char2 = 'A';
   char char3 = 'L';
   char char4 = "I";
   char char5 = "K";

   printf("My name is %c%c%c%c%c",char1,char2,char3,char4,char5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"I"` -> `'I'` and `"K"` -> `'K'`

Comment: Don't you get a "conversion making integer from pointer" warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char char3 = 'L';

char char4 = "I";
```

Can you spot the difference?

If not then the latter is wrong and it should be

```
char char4 = 'I';
```

Comment: thanks bro i forgot to use single quotes i am using double quotes for I and K character that's the reason of getting error